# How to block/reject all incoming packets from Asia?

Tags: firewall, vps

I have my own VPS and I want to block/reject all incoming packets from Asia. Is it possible to do it? My server is on Ubuntu.

Comment: We have many questions about blocking countries in addition to that one. You should take a look through them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that, but it is possible to come close. As a rule, IP address ranges are associated with a region.  Find those ranges, ideally consolidate them, and add them to your firewall.

Unfortunately you will need to update these periodically, and vpns and other things will get in the way.  The solution won't be robust.

You may be able to pick the data you need from a BGP feed (but its complex). If you don't mind blocking the pacific as well, you could look at blocking all the ranges supplied by APNIC (https://www.apnic.net/manage-ip/manage-resources/address-status/apnic-resource-range/) - but that means bye-bye AU and NZ as well, and there are probably quite a few you won't get.

Companies like Maxmind provide curated geographic IP ranges you can use - but it will cost you.